# Chrome disabled possibility of styling range input, is there a way to fix it?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

It looks like Chrome decided to disable part of the styling of input ranges using

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before
```

for example
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582301#c6

I am using ionic for my Android app and it looks like it affects both the Android phone and the browser. Would anyone have a solution that would allow me to style the left side and the right side of the input differently on Android? I don't see a solution myself without having to create a different custom slider.